# Convert 15-bit color space PNG image to text file

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm unsure if imagemagick is able to do this, or if I need to write something myself; but I'd like to convert an image such as the below to a text file such that each line represents a single pixel (reading left to right, top to bottom) and has 15-bits of data on each line (5 bits for R, G, and B).

So for example the below image would have 256x224 = 57,344 lines of 15-bits.

Is imagemagick capable of doing this?  If not is there another resource? Appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the ".txt" output format:

```
magick U4zI6.png U4zI6.txt
```

This will have more voluminous information for each line, but you can
use a text editor such as "sed" to extract the RGB values.

```
$ head -6 U4Zi6.txt
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 256,224,65535,srgb
0,0: (28784,45232,53456)  #70B0D0  srgb(112,176,208)
1,0: (28784,45232,53456)  #70B0D0  srgb(112,176,208)
2,0: (28784,45232,53456)  #70B0D0  srgb(112,176,208)
3,0: (28784,45232,53456)  #70B0D0  srgb(112,176,208)
4,0: (28784,45232,53456)  #70B0D0  srgb(112,176,208)
```

Comment: Glenn, out of curiosity, when I run "magick U4zI6.png -depth 5 U4zI6d5.txt" I get srgb(115,173,206), when I would have expected the first line to be srgb(14,21,25)... am I giving the wrong arguments?  I did my own 8-bit to 5-bit converter in Excel to handle the bit depth but curious if Imagemagick can save that step.

Comment: The srgb intensities are in the range 0:255 (the first triplet is in the range 0:65535).  No, IM doesn't have an internal 8 to 5-bit converter.  If you search this site for RGB555 and RGB565 you'll find a number of relevant questions.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
convert U4zI6.png -depth 8 rgb: | perl -e '
      # Read file, 3 RGB bytes at a time
      {
         local $/ = \3;
         while(my $pixel=<STDIN>){
            my ($r,$g,$b) = unpack("CCC",$pixel);
            printf("In R/G/B: %d/%d/%d\n",$r,$g,$b);
            my $r = ($r >> 3) & 63;
            my $g = ($g >> 3) & 63;
            my $b = ($b >> 3) & 63;
            printf("Out R/G/B: %d/%d/%d\n",$r,$g,$b);
         }
      }
   '
```

Comment: You would get more accurate results with "my $r = (($r+4) >> 3) & 63;", etc.  In effect this rounds instead of just chopping the components.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Thank you for your, as ever, top advice.